# How to make anchor link focus the form field?

Tags: html, forms

I have error messages in anchor tag. When you click on it, it should focus/take the cursor to the respective form field. It works in IE but does not work in FF or Chrome. Am I doing something wrong here?

I have a sample in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/JaaTK/

I don't want to use JavaScript to achieve this.

**EDIT** I will have to go JS route as there doesn't seem to be a better way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need JavaScript for this, since it's not default browser behavior.  Edit: on the chance that you reconsider the JavaScript requirement, here's a jQuery approach: http://jsfiddle.net/JaaTK/1/

Comment: Do you _need_ to have your error messages in an anchor tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('firstName').focus()">Go to first name</a>
```

I think is the only way.

Comment: OP: *I don't want to use JavaScript to achieve this.*

Comment: I am building an accessible form. I am trying to avoid JavaScript as much as I can. I wanted to keep this as a last option.

Comment: I know. But I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Even though I wanted a non JS solution, I guess I don't have a choice. I will accept this as my answer. Thank You.

Comment: Yes you have a choice. See Nick Pavluk's answer.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want use javascript - you have to use “label” tag instead “anchor”, i.e. instead of:

```
<a href="#firstName">Go to the first name</a>
```

you can use:

```
<label for="firstName">Go to the first name</label>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 3):

"I don't want to use JavaScript to achieve this."

Then you are out of luck. Applying focus to an element is JavaScript's job.

UPDATE

So, based on your comment, I think you are asking the wrong question. I think you want to ask:

"Is there a way to make my error messages more accessible?"

The best way to handle that would be for your error messages to link to the form field's LABEL rather than apply auto-focus to the field. At least, that'd be the best way to handle things sans JavaScript.

```
<a href="#fieldlabel1">Error Message</a>

<label for="field1" id="fieldlabel1">Label</label><input id="field1" />
```

Comment: It's not for IE though. I need to consider JS disabled browsers and screen readers.

Comment: Well, IE is usually wrong. I've update my answer with an alternative solution for you.

Comment: Keep in mind that JavaScript isn't necessarily a hindrance to accessibility. Screen readers can handle JavaScript...especially if you start using ARIA attributes.

Comment: That looks like an interesting approach. I like it. But for this purpose, I guess I will just stick with JS. Thanks.

Comment: Using JavaScript is not an accessibility issue, in fact, using it in this way should help keyboard and screen reader users.